# Inverse of a product of functions

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ and $g$ are two measurable functions, $h=fg$ is measurable. Now, if $M$ is any Borel set, what is $h^{-1}(M)$? I am tempted to write $h^{-1}(M)=f^{-1}(M)\cup g^{-1}(M)$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No There is no formula for $h^{-1}(M)$ in terms of $f^{-1}(M)$ and $g^{-1}(M)$.

Comment: Ok, if I may.. how would you check that the product of a measurable function and a locally measurable function is measurable?